# Verificar estado do checkbox - bootstrap switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando [bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) em meus *checkboxes* e gostaria de verificar qual o estado do meu `checkbox` no carregamento da pagina utilizando a própria biblioteca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você utilizar `.bootstrapSwitch('state')`, ele retornara o estado do seu checkbox. Segue os [eventos](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/methods.html) da biblioteca :)

Para pegar o estado após o carregamento da pagina, você pode usar o código abaixo:

```
//evento executado após a pagina ser carregada..
$(document).ready(function() {
    //método para busca do estado
    var state = $("#seuCheckbox").bootstrapSwitch('state');
});
```

Segue o [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/sumw4/511/) :)

Comment: Valeu cara, nao tinha pensado em fazer isso. To quebrando a cabeça tem 2 dias. kkk Muito obrigado mesmo :D

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, estou a disposição :)